# Difference between ORA-12899 and ORA-01480

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle19c

I would like to understand the difference between `ORA-12899` and `ORA-01480`

ORA-12899: value too large for column

ORA-01480: trailing null missing from STR bind value

Based on my understanding, I know about ORA-12899 and how it can come. Lets say if datatype for some column is `VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)` and I am trying to insert more than `100 BYTE` in the column then I am getting ORA-12899.

What about ORA-01480 ? I searchthe ed on internet and and the similar explanation like ORA-12899

> ```
> From google :
>
> ORA-01480: trailing null missing from STR bind value
>
> Cause: A bind variable of type 5 (null-terminated string) does not contain the terminating null in its buffer.
>
> Maybe you're trying to insert a string in a column that is bigger than the column length. So, the terminating character is not being
> inserted at the end of the string.
> ```

Both ORA-12899 and  ORA-01480 look similar. Can someone please explain the exact difference with an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error:

```
ORA-01480: trailing null missing from STR bind value
```

Is for languages such as C or C++ (among many others) which allow low level manipulation of string-like objects.

If you have a `VARCHAR2(100)` column and you try to pass, to a bind variable, the byte array:

```
['h','e','l','l','o']
```

Then you may get the `ORA-01480` error because a `NUL` terminated string is expected and it should have been:

```
['h','e','l','l','o','\0']
```

And the `NUL` character is expected as it allows the SQL engine to determine the length of the `VARCHAR2` variable length string.

---

An example is using Pro*C:

```
char s[2] = "ab";
EXEC SQL SELECT :s into :s2 FROM dual;
```

Outputs: `ORA-01480: trailing null missing from STR bind value`

```
char s[3] = "ab\0";
EXEC SQL SELECT :s into :s2 FROM dual;
```

Works.